# loop through div with different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I generated elements and put them in MyDiv

```
 $("#MyDiv").append('<input type=text class = "form-control" id=tb' + row.PropertyName + ' ' + 'value="Text' + row.PropertyName + '" />');
 $("#MyDiv").append('  <input type="hidden" name="hid" value= "' + row.PropertyId + '">');
```

Now I need to extract the `row.PropertyName` and `row.PropertyId`

I need something like this:

```
    var arrText = new Array();
    $('#MyDiv > input[type = text]').each(function () {

        var id = $(this).id.val();
        var text = $(this).text.val();

        var data = {
            'id': id,
            'text': text
        }
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make it more clear what it is you are building and trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you want.

```js
$(function(){
  var PropertyName = "pn1";
  var PropertyId = "pn2";
$("#MyDiv").append('<input type="text" class = "form-control" id="tb"' + PropertyName + ' ' +
                       'value="Text' + PropertyName + '" />');
 $("#MyDiv").append('  <input type="hidden" name="hid" value= "' + PropertyId + '">');
  
  $('#MyDiv > input[type = "text"]').each(function(){
    
    var id = $(this).val();
    var text = $(this).next('input[type = "hidden"]').val();
    var data = {
      id: id,
      text: text
    }
    alert(data.id + data.text);
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MyDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , well this is what i don't want ... all i want to get is the value of hid hidden filed along with the textbox value

Comment: @Lucy I case you want value of hidden field and the textbox value then use the selectors above. If you dont have multiple inputs then you can simply omit the .each function

Comment: thanks i knew that ... i need to get the text and the id at the same time to fil theobject var data = {id: this.id, name:text}

Comment: @Lucy I hope the current solution shall solve your problem now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrText = [];

$('#MyDiv > input[type=text]').each(function () {
    arrText.push({
        'id': this.id,
        'text': this.value
    });
});

console.log( arrText );
```